# pass specific enum value to method in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, enums, overloading

Altough I already know it's not possible, as my understanding how programming works, I would like to have a confirmation of this.

I have an enum

```
typedef enum {
enum_first=1,
enum_second=2
} myenum
```

I wanted to do overloading of method, this syntax is obviously wrong, but it gives the idea:

```
-(id)myenumTest:(myenum.enum_first)value {...}

-(id)myenumTest:(myenum.enum_second)value {...}
```

Can you suggest an alternative way for this ?

thanks
Leonardo

Comment: Objective-C doesn't support overloading. Outside of C++ templates, no type system I know of allows for overloading methods based on values. Does anyone else know of such beasts?

Comment: Languages with pattern matching like SML and Haskell let you write a function definition like this without an explicit conditional statement. Objective-C certainly doesn't, though.

Comment: @Chuck: those are the beasts!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a case statement within the method based on the value of the enum variable.